# convert java vector element into a string

Tags: java, database, string, jsp, vector

I have a java class with a number of vectors I use this line to add elements from a database...

```
public void addUserSet(ResultSet userData){
    int i = 0;
    while (accountData.next()){
        userID.addElement(new String(userData.getString("User_ID"))); i++;
    }
}
```

also I intend to call it within a jsp page...

> % getUserSet(index); %>

I want to be able to save userID.get(someElement) as a string. not for a System.out.println() which I've seen a lot of but to save as a string so it can be manipulated like a string. What would be the simplest method of doing that?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking but if you call new String() with anything other than an array of bytes or chars, you're doing it wrong.  There's very little reason to ever call String's constructors.

Comment: sorry. that was the only code I found that worked thus far. User_ID is a string that's why I had it as a new string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String s;
int i = 0;

while (accountData.next()){
        s = userData.getString("User_ID");
        //you have s now you can do things with it
        userID.addElement(s); 
        i++;
    }
```

Pretty trivial question, sounds like you need to read some java tutorials:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: actually that's what I had before and I had the same problem. The way I have it up there just seems more fancy to me :) but thanks!